Why am I unable to start a kernel in Jupyter notebook (VS Code)?
I've installed jupyter notebook to my computer since it seems really useful for coding in python. This computer I'm using it on is shared among many other users who've done other coding projects in the past, which could be related to the issue. Whenever I try to run anything in a notebook, it errors out and says:
"Failed to start the Kernel.
Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73).
View Jupyter log for further details."
Few other notes:

This is odd because runneradmin is not a subfolder of C:\Users. I checked if the other users might've had this folder path, but none of them did.
I've reinstalled jupyter & notebook using pip and conda, asked ChatGPT about it, and no help
Consulted other threads to see if their solutions worked for me.
I've attached the Jupyter log (the full thing, but bolded where the error starts) below in case that helps. Sorry about how long the post is.

If you somehow are able to fix this, I will give you a high five.
12:59:54.676 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 0 for ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\basicViT_tf.ipynb

12:59:54.677 [info] Starting Kernel startUsingPythonInterpreter,
.jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe
.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher  
(Python Path: ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe, Venv, general-env, 3.9.13) for '~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\basicViT_tf.ipynb' (disableUI=false)

12:59:54.683 [info] Process Execution: ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel; print(ipykernel.version); print("5dc3a68c-e34e-4080-9c3e-2a532b2ccb4d"); print(ipykernel.file)"

12:59:54.782 [info] Process Execution: ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --f=~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-30360NBakLFF58217.json

> cwd: ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff
12:59:54.782 [info] Kernel process 4636.12:59:55.480 [warn] StdErr from Kernel Process Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)  

Here's the Error:
12:59:55.491 [error] Disposing kernel process due to an error Error: The kernel died. 

Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... 

View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

> Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher

> Interpreter Id = ~\DESKTOP\MANNY\VITSTUFF\GENERAL-ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE

> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:335:2012)

> stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build\_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)

12:59:55.491 [info] Dispose Kernel process 4636.

12:59:55.492 [error] Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

12:59:55.492 [error] Failed to connect raw kernel session: Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

12:59:55.492 [warn] Failed to shutdown kernel, .jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispose')at cT.shutdown (~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:340:15465)at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)at lT.shutdown (~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:340:24053)

12:59:55.494 [warn] Error occurred while trying to start the kernel, options.disableUI=false Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

> Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher

> Interpreter Id = ~\DESKTOP\MANNY\VITSTUFF\GENERAL-ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE

> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:335:2012)

> stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)

12:59:55.494 [warn] Kernel Error, context = start Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

> Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775
.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher

> Interpreter Id = ~\DESKTOP\MANNY\VITSTUFF\GENERAL-ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE

> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:335:2012)

> stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)

12:59:55.499 [info] Process Execution: ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"

12:59:55.863 [info] Dispose Kernel '~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\basicViT_tf.ipynb' associated with '~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\basicViT_tf.ipynb'

12:59:55.864 [error] Error in execution
Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

> Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775
.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher

> Interpreter Id = ~\DESKTOP\MANNY\VITSTUFF\GENERAL-ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE

> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:335:2012)

> stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)

12:59:55.864 [error] Error in execution (get message for cell) Error: The kernel died. Error: Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)... View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.

> Kernel Id = .jvsc74a57bd0111727ead8eb02c2415f0394aa27fc706c14ff95d77d924e1eff5b391d7c1775
.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe.-m#ipykernel_launcher

> Interpreter Id = ~\DESKTOP\MANNY\VITSTUFF\GENERAL-ENV\SCRIPTS\PYTHON.EXE

> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (~.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.2.0-win32-x64\dist\extension.node.js:335:2012)

> stdErr = Bad file descriptor (C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_5uluojy\build_deps\bundled_libzmq-src\src\epoll.cpp:73)

12:59:55.868 [info] Process Execution: ~\Desktop\Manny\ViTstuff\general-env\Scripts\python.exe -c "import ipykernel;print('6af208d0-cb9c-427f-b937-ff563e17efdf')"

12:59:56.237 [info] End cell 0 execution after 0s, completed @ undefined, started @ undefined

